# Trouble populating a bunch of Textboxes with data from a SQLite database in WPF

Tags: database, wpf, sqlite, xaml, data-binding

Currently trying to code a application that will read user data from a SQLite database and populate all of the textboxes with giving parameters. The problem I am having is being able to read that data and then databind it to a textbox. I have already created the database where the user can input the information about the person.

Here is a image of my application:
[[image]]

And then some code snippets of my connection and database:

```
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]

        public int Id { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(35)]
        public string Name { get; set; }


        [MaxLength(5)]
        public string Rate { get; set; }


        public string Senority { get; set; }

        [Ignore]
        public string NameAndRate
        {
            get
            {
                return Rate + Name;
            }
        }
```

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        public static string databaseName = "Contacts.db";
        public static string folderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        public static string databasePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderPath, databaseName);
    }
```

```
private void GenerateList(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(App.databasePath))
            {




            }
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried for data-binding?

Comment: This is my databinding for the textbox

```
<TextBox Width="195" x:Name="Rack3A" Text="{Binding ElementName=dgRack3A, Path=Contacts.Name}"/>

```
@redcurry

Comment: So you're data-binding each `TextBox`? Have you tried using something like a `DataGrid` instead?

Comment: Yes that was the original plan, from the research I gathered I am starting to think I am going to have to use a dataGrid instead. @redcurry